# How to link OpenSSL in windows using MSYS2?

Tags: c++, openssl, msys2

I wrote a c++ program using OpenSSL, it works fine on linux but when I try to compile on windows I get an error that `libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll`, `libssl-1_1-x64.dll` are missing

I am compiling using

```
 g++ main.cpp  -lws2_32 -LC:\msys64\mingw64\bin -IC:\msys64\mingw64\include\openssl
```

Both dll files can be found in `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`, but the executable does not work

Comment: Copy the files and place them next to your executable. Or run with `.../bin` in the PATH. Or link `-static`ally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came up with a simple openssl example and compiled/linked fine

```bash
$ g++ ssltest.cpp  -lssl -lcrypto -o ssltest
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 Fred None  1072 Aug 21 01:18 ssltest.cpp
-rwxr-xr-x 1 Fred None 77824 Aug 21 01:18 ssltest.exe
```

It just works out of the box.
I am using the CLANG64 environment and I have the `mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-openssl` package installed. The files are installed on

```bash
$ pacman -Ql mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-openssl | grep '.dll'
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-openssl /clang64/bin/libcrypto-1_1-x64.dll
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-openssl /clang64/bin/libssl-1_1-x64.dll
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-openssl /clang64/lib/engines-1_1/capi.dll
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-openssl /clang64/lib/engines-1_1/padlock.dll
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-openssl /clang64/lib/libcrypto.dll.a
mingw-w64-clang-x86_64-openssl /clang64/lib/libssl.dll.a
```